# recurrent weights on LSTM Data-gate? (the one with tanh)

Tags: lstm

Looking at the literature, there are 2 distinct approaches to LSTM

---

Some people use recurrent weights with **Input, Forget, Output** - notice, their equations don't even mention dataGate, they start from describing the $f$ or $i$ gate [(1)](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-network-tutorial-part-4-implementing-a-grulstm-rnn-with-python-and-theano/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory): [(2)](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/2db2cba6a0d878e13932fa27ce6f3fb71ad99cf1)

Lke this:

[image]

---

Other people use recurrent weights with **dataGate (z), Input, Forget, Output** [(1)](https://saurabhmathur96.github.io/deep-learning-notes/LSTM%20A%20Search%20Space%20Odyssey) [(2)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Occam-s-Gates-Raiman-Sidor/733ab0a2c81a55a41734e5171f1ac16882ecca6c/figure/0)  [(3)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17412/43077), [(4)](http://nlpapps.nl/article1.html)

Like this:

[image]

Having tried the first approach (**I still used standard weights on dataGate but no recurrent weights in that place**) seems fine but a little odd - network converges well, but very rarely jumps over local mimima, as if too high learning rate.

Personally I like the second approach (recurrent weights on all 4 entry points), which one do I use?

---

**Edit:**

to make things worse, the ["LSTM Peephole paper", page 121](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/gers02a/gers02a.pdf) describes 3 connections (no peephole for dataGate).

This destroys the equal-sizes of my matrices, because now 3 gates use the Usual, Recurrent and Peephole weights, but the very first gate only uses the Usual weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both of the examples in the question were identical.
It's just that in the first example, $\sigma_c$ denotes that tanh (on the 4th line).

And in the second example, they actually write $tanh$ on a separate line. It's just syntaxis.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than two or three variants with regards to LSTM.

A paper that explores these variants can be read here:

[LSTM:A Search Space Odyssey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04069.pdf)